# Highcharts spider chart with radial gradient fill not centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have a spider web highcharts that is filled with radial gradient. When all edges have same value, the gradient is fine. But when it has random values, gradient doesn't fill right. It's off the center and becomes oval shaped.

```
var highChartsData = {
chart: {
  polar: true,
  type: 'area',
  events: {
        load: function () {series = this.series[0];}
    }
},
xAxis: {
  categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
  tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
  lineWidth: 0

},
yAxis: {
  gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
  lineWidth: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 12
},
tooltip: {
    enabled: false
},
title: {
    enabled: false
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
exporting: {
  enabled: false
},
legend: {
  enabled: false
},
series: [{
  name: 'Planning',
  type: 'area',
  color: {
    radialGradient: {
        cx: 0.5,
      cy: 0.5,
      r: 1
    },
    stops: [
      [0, 'rgba(147, 255, 228, 0.8)'],
      [1, 'rgba(0, 105, 165,1)']
    ]
  },
  data: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
  pointPlacement: 'on'
}]};
```

Check this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/a6fmfq1a/44/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

The original solution that I proposed didn't handle the shape of the gradient - it could be oval instead of perfect circle.

Using `gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'` seems to be a better and simplier approach.

```
  defs: {     
    gradient1: { // key
      tagName: 'radialGradient',
      id: 'gradient-1',
      gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse',     
      cx: 300,
      cy: 160,
      r: 300,
      children: [{
        tagName: 'stop',
        'stop-color': 'rgba(0, 255, 0,1)',
        offset: 0
      }, {
        tagName: 'stop',
        'stop-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
        offset: 0.3
      }]
    }
  },
```

**CSS:**

```
.highcharts-area {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill: url(#gradient-1);
}
```

**Live demo:** https://fiddle.jshell.net/kkulig/vokL08ds/

This example uses **styled mode** (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css).

---

### Original post:

It seems that the center of the **SVG gradient** is based on the minimum and maximum coordinates values of the shape itself and not the whole chart.

<s>**The solution** here is to manually compute and apply the offset for `radialGradient.cx` and `radialGradient.cy` properties.</s>

In this **live demo** it's done only for the **x** value (y value need to be handled analogically): https://fiddle.jshell.net/kkulig/ru85bz24/

```
// handle gradient center
var x1, // leftmost
  x2, // rightmost
  centerX,
  offsetPx,
  offsetAdjustment = -3;

x1 = x2 = series.points[0].graphic.x;

// find leftmost and righmost x positions
series.points.forEach(function(p) {
  var x = p.graphic.x;
  if (x < x1) {
    x1 = x;
  } else if (x > x2) {
    x2 = x;
  }
});

// compute offset
centerX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
offsetPx = (chart.chartWidth / 2) - centerX + offsetAdjustment;
offsetFraction = offsetPx / (x2 - x1);


// update gradient
series.update({
  color: {
    radialGradient: {
      cx: 0.5 + offsetFraction,
      cy: 0.5,
      r: 1
    }
  }
});
```

To see the effect click `Toggle Contrast` first and then `Toggle Numbers`.

Highcharts doesn't put the center of the plot exactly in the center of the chart so I added `offsetAdjustment` variable that corrects the position of the gradient (3px in this case).

Comment: That kind of works but how about 'Y's? The gradient is still oval